# Get out an error message if noone of checkboxes selected

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have set a checkboxes form that works perfect, i have this if statement which also works perfect but what i really want is when the user hasn't selectected any checkbox from the list, when he pushes the save button to get out a drupal error that will says "Oh!you do not select nothing"... How i can do this thing?

```
if (!$selected) {
  drupal_set_message(t('You have to select at least one option from the list.'), 'warning');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the message manually from your code:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7

Where you have that your if logic add drupal_set_message() call.

Comment: it does not work for me i correct my code look...That code do not work... :'( :'( :'(

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Form API?

If yes try the #required property

```
     $form['test'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#options' => $myOptions,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t('Test'),
     )
```

Comment: with #required it shows me no messages i want to show me an error message with some sentence that i want..